# Filter Sub form values from Parent Form in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I’m hoping someone can help me with this. I’ve been struggling for a while trying to figure out how to make this work.

I have a Main form called frm_main, and a subform called sub_Devs. Both forms are connected through a WorkOrderID. I would like to filter through the sub_Devs form and find different work orders with specific Device types, Device Manufacturers, and Models using cascading list boxes but I don't seem to be able to grasp the concept nor get any of the sample codes I've googled to work. This is what I have so far

```
        Private Sub listModel_Click()
        Dim SQL As String
        
        SQL = "SELECT tbl_Devs.Model, tbl_Devs.[WorkOrderID] FROM tbl_Devs" & vbCrLf & _
           "Where Model = Forms!frm_Main!listModel ;"
        
       ' Debug.Print strSQL
        Me.Project.Form.RecordSource = SQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Try concatenating reference to form control. Is Model a text field? `"WHERE Model = '" & Me.Parent.listModel & "';"` Normally, subform does not dictate to main form. Normal approach is to apply filter to main form and subform follows along. Controls used to enter filter criteria must be UNBOUND. Advise to apply filter criteria instead of changing form RecordSource.

Comment: Hello ! The Model is a text field and the controls I'm using are unbound. The only field they have in common is the WorkOrderID. If I cycle through the different work orders I can see all the fields on the subform change but if I want to filter on a specific Model value I can't seem to get it to work. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: Please describe the specific issues you face. *does not work* is not specific enough. Please relay any errors or undesired results including if nothing happens.